# Проверка наличия класса

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код "корзины", как можно сделать проверку наличия класса, если класс уже есть, то вместо добавления нового блока увеличивать значение input'а на 1.

```
  <script>
      $(".buyprod").click(function () {
        var img = $(this).parent().find("img").attr("src");
        var i=1;
        $("#cartdiv").append('<div class="module_holder"><div class="module_item'+i+'"><img src="'+ img +'" alt="photo1"><br><p><input type="number" value="1" min="0" max="5" step="1"></div></div>');
        i++;
      });
  </script>
```

Нужно проверить если класс module_item+i(номер блока), уже существует, то увеличить значения инпута.Нашел ещё ошибку, классы повторяться не будут, как можно сделать чтобы i при нажатии на определённый блок имело своё значение?

Comment: ну дак и поищите его `$("#cartdiv").find(".module-item" + i)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
if ($('selector').hasClass('your-class')) {
  const input = $('input');
  input.val(input.val()++);
}
```

Comment: Класс не находиться на одном уровне с selector, совпадений не находит

Comment: подскажите в чём может быть проблема?

Comment: В этом примере класс должен быть у самого элемента `selector`.
Если класс находится внутри  `selector`, то как подсказал @teran, можно сделать `$('selector').find('.you-class').length > 0` или даже  `$('selector .your-class').length > 0`, чтоб шустрее отработало. Если же класс находится на том же уровне что и `selector`, то, пожалуй самый простой способ будет `$('selector').siblings('.your-class').length > 0` или даже `$('selector + .you-class').length > 0`, чтоб отработало на микросекунду быстрее.